# How do I get my array to return an int array to be used in another function?

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, return

I need the function drop_balls to return an array so that I can make my next function use that array. I need it to take in an integer as a parameter, and then return an int array so that it can be used in another function that I will be making after. I have been reading that it can only be passed as a pointer, but I have absolutely no idea how that would be coded, can someone please help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


/* Prototype for drop_Balls, int parameter is number of balls being dropped */
int [] drop_balls(int); 

/* Gets the number of balls that need to be dropped by the user */
int get_num_balls(); 


int main()
{
    drop_balls(get_num_balls());
}


int get_num_balls()
{
    int num_balls;
    printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_balls);
    /* Ensure that it is atleast one ball */
    while(num_balls <= 0) 
    {
        printf("You have to drop at least one ball! \n ");
        printf("How many balls should be dropped? ");
        scanf("%d", &num_balls);
    }
    /* Return the number of balls that will be dropped */
    return num_balls; 
}



int [] drop_balls(int num_balls)
{
    /* Keeps track of how many balls landed where */
    int ball_count[21]; 
    /* What number ball are we on */
    int ball_num = 0; 
    /* Seed the generator */
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    /* Do the correct # of balls */
    for(ball_num = 0; ball_num < num_balls; ball_num++ ) 
    {
  /* Start at 10 since its the middle of 21 */
        int starting_point = 10; 
    /* Bounce each ball 10 times */
        for(starting_point = 10; starting_point > 0; starting_point--) 
        {
           int number;
       /* Create a random integer between 1-100 */
           number = rand() % 100; 
       /* If its less than 50 bounce to the right once */
           if(number >= 50) 
           {
               starting_point++;
           }
       /* If its greater than 50, bounce to the left once */
           else 
           {
               starting_point--;
           }
        }
    /* Add one to simulate one ball landing there */
        ball_count[starting_point]++;  
    }
    return ball_count;
}
```

Comment: What happens with the code you have so far?

Comment: Use a std::vector<int>

Comment: @mikejones that is c++, OP is asking about c

Comment: Considering what you seem to be trying to do, why not simply declare `int ball_count[21]` as a global variable and be done with it? If this is just a very small program...

Comment: @dmitri normally I wouldn't recommend it, but if you examine the OP's code the size is already hardcoded and it's a simulation of dropping balls through one of those pin grids. If that's all there is to the program then I think a global is fine and malloc is overkill.

Comment: Not for nothing .. but it would be highly advisable to put your `srand(time(NULL))` statement in the main and right in the begining

Comment: Your title is "How do I get my array to return an int array to be used in another function?". Don't you mean "How do I get my *function* ..."?

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to pass an array of integers `balls` to you function `drop_balls` it would be declared like so:

```
void drop_balls(int **balls);

int main ()
{
    int *balls; /* This is your array of balls*/

    /* Allocate memory for `number_of_balls` number of balls */
    balls = malloc(number_of_balls * sizeof(*balls));
    if (balls == NULL)
         printf("Error: failed to allocate memory");

    /* call the function by passing the pointer to your array of balls */
    drop_balls(&balls);

    free(balls);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to pass int ** into drop_balls, rather than int *? I do not think this is required in this case.

Comment: The entire program is supposed to ask the user how many balls they want to drop. Simulate dropping that many balls, and allow them to bounce ten times either once to the left or right. Then print out the array, showing an 'o' for each ball that fell in each place.

Comment: The entire program is supposed to ask the user how many balls they want to drop. Simulate dropping that many balls, and allow them to bounce ten times either once to the left or right. Then print out the array, showing an 'o' for each ball that fell in each place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an array that was declared as a local variable in the function. It lives on the stack, and it will no longer exist once the function returns. You would be returning the address of where the array *had been*, which would be bad.

Instead, you need to create the array on the heap, using `malloc,` and return a pointer to it. You will need to check that this pointer is not `NULL,` and you will need to call `free` to release the memory when you are done with it. You should change the return type of your function to `int *` as well.

Answer (score -1):

An example of a function that returns an array would be `malloc()`, a standard library function. You may write your own function that allocates an array, does something with it and returns it back to a caller:

```
int *function_returning_an_array_of_size_n(int n)
{
   int *array = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
   // do something useful with the array
   // ...
   return array;
}
```

An example of a function that takes an array as a parameter is `free()`, again a standard library function.

Here is how you would write a function that receives an array as a parameter.

```
void function_receiving_an_array_and_size_n(int *array, int n)
{
   // Do something with array. If accessing elements beware the array size violation.
}
```

I am passing an additional parameter, the array size. Without knowing the size it'l be dangerous to access elements of the array.

Comment: This doesn't compile. The question is about c, not c++.

Comment: @DavidConrad I replaced new with malloc